# Retrieve data from another table upon form submit

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have a form on my site that users fill in upon registration. All the registration are stored in the "registration" table. the table structure look like this:
id, username, password, firstname, lastname, email, gender, jobtitle, f1, country, f2, fbook, f3, fmovie, f4.

the ***jobtitle***, ***country***, ***fbook*** and ***fmovie*** are dropdown menus. the values of those dropdwon menus are also stored in another table called "extrainfo" with this structure:
jobtitle, f1, country, f2, fbook, f3, fmovie, f4.

When the user submits the form, it should check the values in the jobtitle, country, fbook and fmovie field and retrieve the values from the "extrainfo" table.

So if the user chooses "DECORATOR" in the jobtitle dropdown menu it should get the value from the f1 column in the "extrainfo" table and insert it in the f1 column in the "registration" table.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You achieve that by reading in the submitted value and compare it against the data in your database with a SQL query by selecting the row where the data matches.

Comment: Example for what? How to run a select query? Sure, it's in the manual:  [SELECT Syntax (MySQL)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

After form submission try like this

Get the value of select box by $_POST

```
$jobtitle = $_POST['jobtitle']; //name of select box is assumed as jobtitle
```

Get the values from extrainfo

```
$r = mysql_query("select f1 from extrainfo where jobtitle='$jobtitle'); //get f1 from extrainfo
$j = mysql_fetch_row($r);
```

Insert into registration table like this for all columns

```
mysql_query("insert into registration(f1)values('$j[0]')"); //insert the f1 into registration table
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just build the drop-downs with the values already in them rather than look them up afterwards:

```
<SELECT name="jobtitle">
    <OPTION value="f1_value">Decorator</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="f1_value">Welder</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

where `f1_value` is the value from the `extrainfo` table for each jobtitle. You could also use a `foreach` structure to build the `<OPTION>...</OPTIONS>` if you read the information in to an array first:

```
<?php
$q="select * from extrainfo";
if ($r=mysql_query($q))
{
  $m=array();
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($m))
  {
    $m[]=$row;
  }
?>
<SELECT name="jobtitle">
<?php
  foreach ($m as $line)
  {
    echo '<OPTION value="'.$line['f1'].'">'.$line['jobtitle'].'</OPTION>';
  }
?>
</SELECT>
```